# Artifactory - Can we set permissions on a directory level

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-cli

Is it possible to set different permissions for directories in the same repository?

Can we set permissions on a directory level or only on repository level?

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can, by using `Include` and `Exclude` patterns on a [Permission Target](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Managing+Permissions#ManagingPermissions-CreatingaPermissionTarget)